# using u_context structs - what is uc_stack.ss_flags used for?

Tags: c++, linux

I am attempting to manipulate threads in a C++ application using getContext() and setContext(). I noticed the ucontext_t struct has this field, uc_stack.ss_flags. What can these flags be used for? I am wondering how they could be used for garbage collection in a thread library. Usually they are set to zero by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `sigstack.h` I see:

```
/* Possible values for `ss_flags.'.  */
enum
{
  SS_ONSTACK = 1,
#define SS_ONSTACK  SS_ONSTACK
  SS_DISABLE
#define SS_DISABLE  SS_DISABLE
};
```

Search for those takes us here:
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sigaltstack.html

Which says:

> - **SS_ONSTACK** The process is currently executing on the alternate signal
>     stack. Attempts to modify the alternate signal stack while the process
>     is executing on it fail. This flag shall not be modified by processes.
> - **SS_DISABLE** The alternate signal stack is currently disabled.